How to fix 502 Bad Gateway response for NGINX-ingress for Splunk-services?
I would like to share my configuration for setting up an NGINX Ingress for the Splunk Web UI, Splunk HTTP Event Collector, and the splunkd REST API. Initially, I configured backend-protocol: "HTTP", which led to a 502 Bad Gateway error. So, be sure to use backend-protocol: "HTTPS".
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-splunk
  namespace: splunk
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"  # HTTP causes 502 Bad Gateway
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "200m"    # Upload up to 200 MB
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: "splunkweb.dev"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: splunk-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
    - host: "hec.dev"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: splunk-service
                port:
                  number: 8088
    - host: "splunkd.dev"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: splunk-service
                port:
                  number: 8089

The Ingress backend is the corresponding Splunk service in the cluster, which maps to the container ports of the Splunk pod.
Make sure the local DNS points to the IP address of the Ingress controller. In my case, it was just my localhost, so I added splunkweb.dev, hec.dev, and splunkd.dev to my local hosts file and pointed them to 127.0.0.1.
Are there any more configuration suggestions that may improve the setup for scalability and performance?
It took me almost two entire days to fix the 502 Bad Gateway response.
My setup is a Windows 11 machine running WSL 2. I have installed Rancher Desktop 1.13.1, disabled Traefik, and installed the NGINX Ingress controller.
The NGINX logs clearly showed the 502 errors and indicated that the backend actively refused the connection. However, they did not specify WHY it refused it.
This is the according service configuration
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: splunk-service
  labels:   
    app: my-splunk-app
    component: splunk
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
      app: my-splunk-app
      component: splunk
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: port-8000
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
    - protocol: TCP
      name: port-8088
      port: 8088
      targetPort: 8088
    - protocol: TCP
      name: port-8089
      port: 8089
      targetPort: 8089
    - protocol: TCP
      name: port-9997
      port: 9997
      targetPort: 9997

The service maps to the container-Ports of the splunk deployment:
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: splunk
  labels:
    app: my-splunk-app
    component: splunk
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-splunk-app
      component: splunk
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-splunk-app
        component: splunk
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsGroup: 0
        fsGroup: 0
      containers:
      - name: splunk
        image: {{ printf "%s:%s" .Values.splunk.image .Values.splunk.version }}
        env:
        - name: SPLUNK_START_ARGS
          value: --accept-license
        - name: SPLUNK_PASSWORD
          value: {{ .Values.splunk.password }}
        - name: SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN
          value: {{ .Values.splunk.hecToken }}
        - name: SPLUNK_HEC_PORT
          value: '8088'
        - name: SPLUNK_HTTP_ENABLESSL
          value: 'true'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000 # WEB UI
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8088 # default HEC port
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8089 # local splunkd management port
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9997 # forwarding and receiving
          protocol: TCP

After many attempts, adding the backend-protocol: "HTTPS" annotation to the ingress template finally fixed the error. I hope this helps anyone who encounters a 502 Bad Gateway response from the NGINX Ingress in front of Splunk services, as I was unable to find any helpful information in Splunk's documentation.
Any suggestions for improving the setup for scalability and performance are very welcome.
Cheers, Loop
